# Which left-hand side matrix $A$ distinguishes these four binary vectors from all others?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vectors

I am using matrix multiplication of the form $\boldsymbol{A} \cdot x = b$ to formulate the (in)equality constraints for a mixed-integer (more precisely: binary) linear optimization problem.

I need to constrain the possible solution space. Therefore, I am looking for a matrix $\boldsymbol{A} \in \mathbb{R}$ of shape *(m, 8)* which, when multiplied with the following *(8,1)* $x$ vectors, gives the null vector $b = \vec 0_{(m, 1)}$, i.e.:

$$
\boldsymbol{A} \cdot (0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0)^T = \vec 0_{(m, 1)} \\
\boldsymbol{A} \cdot (1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)^T = \vec 0_{(m, 1)} \\
\boldsymbol{A} \cdot (0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)^T = \vec 0_{(m, 1)} \\
\boldsymbol{A} \cdot (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)^T = \vec 0_{(m, 1)}
$$

All other variants of $x$, e. g.:
$$
x = (0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0)^T \\
x = (0, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 1, 1)^T
$$
should give something unequal to $\vec 0_{(m, 1)}$.

Is there a unique solution for $\boldsymbol{A}$? If so, how can I find it?

Comment: Note that your first equation $A\cdot \vec 0 = \vec 0$ is true for every matrix $A$.  The fourth equation is implied by the second and third equations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Essentially we need that $v_1=(1, 1, 1, 1, 0, 0, 0, 0)^T$ and $v_2=(0, 0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 1)^T$ are vectors in the null space of $A$ therefore we can choose as columns of $A$ vectors $w_1,\ldots,w_8$ such that

- $w_1+w_2+w_3+w_4=0$
- $w_5+w_6+w_7+w_8=0$

with $6$ of them linearly independent, that is for example

- $w_1=e_1, w_2=e_2,w_3=e_3,w_4=-e_1-e_2-e_3$
- $w_5=e_5, w_6=e_6,w_7=e_7,w_8=-e_5-e_6-e_7$

with $e_1=(1,0,\ldots,0)^T$ and so on.